# Set and Display Dates in rails via format: %m/%d/%Y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

If you want to save a `date` attribute in a rails form via a text_field: by default rails wants you to put the date in the format of: `%Y-%m-%d`. ex: '2016-8-25'.

- I want to put the date in the format of `%m/%d/%Y`. ex: '8/25/2016'.
- When editing this date attribute: I want it to also display the date in that same format.

I have this specified in my `config/locals/en.yml` file but it is not working:

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%m/%d/%Y"
```

If there is another strategy different from above: let me know.

Ultimately: all my date attributes application wide use the [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails).  Within forms: this gem wants dates to be in the above format, and it makes sense for dates to be in that format anyways. I do not want to have to override all the writer attributes in order for rails to understand this format.

---

### Update

There appears to be some confusion about my stack overflow question.  Users are not actually manually entering dates.  They are using a datepicker.  And when the user picks a date: it saves the date in a textbox with the format of: mm/dd/yyyy. This is how the clients of this small, in-house app want to display the date (and it makes sense that they want the date displayed this way because they live in the United States and this is a typical date format there).

Ultimately here is the scenario:

Here is the relevant input field in the form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :some_date %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :some_date, data: {provide: 'datepicker'} %>
</div>
```

If you manually enter the string: `2016-1-20`, and then submit that:

- Rails *knows* how to take that string of `2016-1-20`, convert it into a date, and then save that date into the database.
- Rails also *knows* how to redisplay that date within the format of `2016-1-20` if the user wants to go back and edit that date.

I want the exact same setup.  The only thing I want to change is the format.  Change the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` to `mm/dd/yyyy`.  So the user would pick a date, and into the input field the value `1/20/2016` would go.  That would get submited.

- Rails would *know* how to convert that to a date and save it to the database.
- If the user wants to edit this date in the future: it would redisplay in the text field the date in the format of `1/20/2016`.

Hopefully this clears up any confusion.

Comment: Don't allow dates to be entered via a text field, and don't use `%m/%d/%Y`. That instantly allows international dates to be misinterpreted. There are fewer places on earth that use `%m/%d/%Y` than `%d/%m/%Y` or `%Y-%m-%d`, so the odds of you getting a value that is malformed increases. Plus, dates are notoriously difficult to enter for users, which is why it's so prevalent to have date pickers, which force the date format into an expected format. This reduces frustration for users and you, when the entered date crashes or is misinterpreted.

Comment: @theTinMan look at the bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails.  It always saves the date in the correct format when using the date picker, and if the users does manually enter the date: it corrects the users input so that it is correct.  My app is not international.  It is for a small business.  Users are not actually manually entering dates. The text field is just a placeholder for the date picker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I have found is a two-step process:

1. **Allow dates to save within the format of mm/dd/yyyy**

   Simply add in the [american_date](https://rubygems.org/gems/american_date) gem. And with that: when you enter into a text_field for a date the format of: `mm/dd/yyyy` (ex: 1/30/2016) it will save the correct date! This works wonderfully with the [bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-datepicker-rails) because when you use the datepicker to pick a date: it loads into the textbox the date in this format.
2. **Display dates in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`**

   however, even with the american_date gem installed: rails still wants to display the date in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

   ***Example***: within a text_field, such as: `<%= f.text_field :date %>`, when the user goes back to `edit` that date, it will redisplay the date in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` which is not what we want.  We want rails to redisplay the date in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

   ***Another Example***:  if  you have an erb tag, such as `<%= @blog.some_date %>` then yet again: rails will display the date in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.  Again: this is not what we want.  We want that erb tag to automatically redisplay the date in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`

   To fix this: you have two options:

   One option is to open up your `config/locals/en.yml` file and use the setup specified in the original question of this post.  I personally do not like this setup because you then need to remember to use the `l` method everytime you want to display a date within your app.

   The other option (which I like best) is to go to your `config/initializers` directory and make a new file.  Name the file anything you want.  I named the file `date_display_format.rb`.  Then within there just put this line: `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"`.  Now: a date within your erb tags will display in the proper format, and when you go to edit your `date` attribute within a form: with the text box the date will display in the proper format as well.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the `l` method in your views using this method? It won't work otherwise.

So it looks like this:

```
<%= l your_date %>
```

An alternative approach could be creating a file in your config/initializers folder, which can be called date_time.rb for example, and then use this:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I read about `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y" ` before but it doesn't work.  For example: try saving the date `1/20/2016`.  Rails doesn't know how to do it so it just doesn't save anything. It can't do it because it still thinks the middle number is for the month.  For example: save `1/12/2016` and it will save the date December 1st, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the date in the format you want, you can use the builtin `strftime`.

For example, if you were displaying the created_at date of an item, you could use the following code to display the saved date in the format of month, day, year. This code would go in a page in your views:

```
@item.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Or the updated_at date:

```
@item.updated_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

This would show the created date in the format you want. Then, when you edit it, it will still be displayed in the month, day, year format.

Comment: This would require a lot of work (custom controller or model methods) in order to do it this way for an app that has a lot of date attributes.  There must be a way of passing in a date param, and rails can automatically infer the date and save the date.  For example: rails automatically can infer and save a date if the `date` param is in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`.  I want to just do the exact same thing except with the format being `mm/dd/yyyy`. Does this make sense? If I can do this then there is no customaization needed at all for any date attributes.